# Why does my mosaic not render anything at deeper zoom levels, when the individual rasters are perfectly visible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

We currently generate a mosaic dataset from rasters. We can zoom in as far as we can into the individual rasters. However, nothing is rendered when we attempt to zoom at the same depth on the mosaic. Why is that? What can we do to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Most likely, pyramids have not been built for the mosaic. Have you tried the Build Pyramids tool?

Comment: Pyramid generation didn't seem to help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Calculate Cell Size Ranges](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-cell-size-ranges.htm) resolved the issue for me. I'm not entirely sure why..